# Replace value inside a word using RazorEngine

Tags: c#, parsing, razorengine

For example I have

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.ClientName = "StackOverFlow";
string result = Razor.Parse("AccountValidation@Model.ClientNameText", model);
```

This code currently fails which is normal.

I would want my result to be "AccountValidationStackOverFlowText"

Is there some kind of escape character to make this work ? for example

```
AccountValidation[@Model.ClientName]Text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for what you want is: `text@(yourcodehere)text`

```
<p>AccountValidation@(Model.ClientName)Text</p>
```

In your case I'd do:

```
string result = "AccountValidation" + model.ClientName + "Text";
```

Comment: Thanks ! this was just an example, I'm actually parsing a whole file.